# How read .shp files in databricks from filestore?

Tags: pyspark, geopandas, databricks-community-edition

I'm using Databricks community, and I save a .shp in the FileStore, but when I tried to read I get this error:

```
DriverError: /dbfs/FileStore/tables/World_Countries.shp: No such file or directory
```

this is my Code

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/World_Countries.shp")
```

I also tried

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("/FileStore/tables/World_Countries.shp")
```

Comment: can you confirm with a shell command that those files are where you think they are?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with the community edition, but I can see it when navigate to the path, also using dbutils, so I think it should be there.